# Result of a combo box / list box selection from word document A into a word document B in a bookmark

Tags: vba, hyperlink, ms-word, listbox, bookmarks

I would like the result of a combo box / list box selection in word document  A to be inserted into a word document B in a bookmark location, in a specific file directory, using VBA.

I have so far but does not work:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

ComboBox1.List = Array("Township Establishment", "Division of Township", "Rezone", "Consent Use", "Written Consent A", "Written Consent B", "Temporary Use", "Subdivision", "Consolidation")

Dim strInput As String
strInput = ComboBox1
Dim WriteToBookmarkRange As String


Dim rng1 As Word.Range
Dim rng2 As Word.Range
Dim strTheText As String
Dim DestFileNum As Long
Dim sDestFile As String

sDestFile = "A:\ToDo-Hermann\Hermann Target.docm" 'Location of external file
DestFileNum = FreeFile()


Open sDestFile For Output As DestFileNum 'This opens new file with name DestFileNum
Set ActiveDocument.rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range
Set ActiveDocument.rng1 = Documents("Hermann Target").Bookmarks("bm1").Range.Text

If ComboBox1 = "Township Establsihment" Then

    Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
    If rng2.Find.Execute(FindText:="Consolidation") Then

        strTheText = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, rng2.Start).Text
        MsgBox strTheText 'writes string to a message box
        Print #DestFileNum, strTheText 'Print # will write to external file with the text strTheText
    
    End If
    
End If

Close #DestFileNum 'Close the destination file
```

Comment: "does not work" is not a very good description of the error. Please add more details to your question by asking an actual question.

Comment: "does not work"  - How do I get the selection result from a list box / combo box selected in document A to be inserted into a bookmark in document B, without opening document B?  Document B is located in a specific file in another directory than document A.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: How do you plan to modify a document without opening it? Where the file resides is not relevant.

Comment: If the document must be opened and closed it should happen so that the user would not be aware of this nor able to input anything manually into document B?  If this can happen in the background if possible?

Comment: yes, that's possible. when you create the word application object, you can just set the visible property to false. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073228/how-to-make-microsoft-word-visible-after-opening-an-excel-file-in-word-vba

Comment: If you had to re-write the code to accomplish what I have in mind how would you write this?

Comment: I would create a new Word application object, which creates a new instance of Word, just like it shows in the example i provided.

Comment: I see, tx.  How do I get the rest of the problem resolved, getting the selection from the list box to document B?

Comment: You only really need to use Documents.Open Filename:=sDestFile, Visible:=False to open a document reasonably silently - assuming that it hasn't got some feature that causes Word to ask for some kind of response. But what is not at all clear from your description is what text you want to put in it - you have a Combo Box, and you say you want to insert one of the dropdown values (which might not be the same as the value entered in the textbox part of the combo, but what you code is currently doing is locating a piece of text depending on the value of the dropdown. Which is it?

Comment: It would only be the text value that is presented in the list box / combo box.  The user will not be able to add his own text to the selection, only what text values available for selection in the list box / combo box.  Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

(Answer modified following a reminder in the comments)

Still not sure exactly what you need to get from the Combo Box, but the _DropButtonClick event will return whatever *was* selected when you click the drop button. Maybe better to use the _Click event and return the .Value of the Checkbox.

So you need something like this:

```
Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim target As Word.Document
Dim targetbm As Word.Bookmark
Dim targetBmName as String
Set target = Documents.Open(Filename:=sDestFile, Visible:=False)
targetbMName = "bm1"
If target.Bookmarks.Exists(targetBmName) Then
  Set rng = target.Bookmarks(targetBmName).Range
  rng.Text = Combobox1.Value ' may need something else here
  ' re-insert the bookmark
  rng.Bookmarks.Add targetBmName
  Set rng = Nothing
  target.Close wdSaveChanges
Else
  ' maybe you also want to log a problem if the bookmark isn't there.
  target.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
End If
Set target = Nothing
```

Comment: Why not just use If target.Bookmarks.Exists(targetBmName)

Comment: @TimothyRylatt you’re right. I always forget that Exists is a member of the collection, not the item.

Comment: Thank you it works like a charm.  Kindly indicate how this would work for multiple target documents.

Comment: @Hermann If you are trying to update *all* the documents in a specified set of folders, there are other Questions here on SO and elsewhere that should help you with that. If you need to update *multiple* boomarks then you you should aim to have a *loop* that opens each document in turn, and an internal loop that updates each bookmark.